# iOS arc4random NOT beginning from 0

Tags: ios

i used arc4random to create a random number, is there a way to tell arc4random to begin at for example -5 instead of 0? because i want to create a random number in the range of 
 -3,4 to 4,3, im not that good in iOS developing yet, so what other possiblities do i have if that wont work with arc4random (Links are appreciated if theres a guide or something like that)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, use `arc4random_uniform` to get a random number in the desired absolute range (for -3 to 4 it would be 7): `arc4random_uniform(7)`.

You might also see the form `arc4random() % max`, but that will introduce a modulo bias making the distribution less random, `arc4random_uniform` is prefered.

Afterwards, adjust your lower bound:

```
arc4random_uniform(7) - 3
```

[apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/arc4random.3.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since `arc4random() % n` returns an integer from 0..n-1, `arc4random() % (n - k) + k` returns one from k..n-1. Plug in k=-5. Is that what you need?

Comment: According to the docs: "arc4random_uniform() is recommended over constructions like ``arc4random() % upper_bound'' as it avoids
     "modulo bias" when the upper bound is not a power of two."

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to start at -5 instead of 0, just subtract 5.

If you want to create a random number in the range of -3 to 4, just create a number from 0 to 7 and subtract 3 from it.

The `arc4random` function gives you a number from zero to 4,294,967,295. To change that to a number from 0 to 7, just divide by 613,566,756. (Or use `arc4random_uniform` to avoid any bias.)